# the period of a trigonometric function

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, trigonometry

I'm trying to solve a differential equation which is :

$$y'(t)-4y(t) = \cos(3t)$$

Resolution of the equation without the second membre $y'(t)-4y(t)=0$ has as
solution $ y_s(t)=ke^{4t} $ with $k\in\mathbb{R}$.

The second member is a trigonometric function, and I need to know it's period $T$, to search for a particular solution in the form of a trigonometric function with the same period.

How could I know what is the period of a trigonometric function ?

Comment: Why not choose $y_p = a \cos 3t + b \sin 3t$, substitute it back into the DEQ and solve for the constants by equating both sides? Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The period of $\cos(ax)$ and $\sin(ax)$ is $\frac{2\pi}{a}$, as

$$ \cos(ax + 2\pi) = \cos(ax) \quad \forall a \in \mathbb R \backslash \{0\}$$

So, to find out the period of a trigonometric function $f(x)$, find the value $k$, such that

$$f(x + k) = f(x)$$

Then $k$ is the period you're looking for.

Comment: so the period of $cos(ax)$ is $2π/a$, and in my function the period is $T=2π/3$ , isn't it ?

Comment: @AimadMajdou Yes, you are right - I forgot to add the $a$ in my initial formula, as I added it afterwards. In fact $a$ represents the frequency, and $1/a$ is the period (but not in "$\pi$-coordinates", that's why you need to multiply it with $2\pi$. So the period of $T$ is $2\pi/3$.

Comment: okey, thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Use operator $D = \dfrac{d}{dx}$
$$
y^{\prime} - 4y = \cos(3t) \quad \Rightarrow \quad (D - 4)y = \cos(3t) \quad \Rightarrow \quad y(t) = \dfrac{1}{D - 4}\cdot 0 +  \dfrac{1}{D - 4}\cos(3t) \ \Rightarrow
$$ 
$$
y(t) = Ce^{4t} + \dfrac{D + 4}{D^2 - 16}\cos(3t) = Ce^{4t} + \dfrac{D\cos(3t) + 4\cos(3t)}{-3^2 - 16} \quad \Rightarrow
$$
$$
y(t) = Ce^{4t} - \dfrac{1}{25}[4\cos(3t)-3\sin(3t)]
$$
Therefore, the period of the particular solution is $T = 2\pi/3$.